# Gallery of image scrolls with center image looks bigger always in android

Tags: android

I'm doing an Android application which has list of image gallery to be displayed in iphone like styles such as images should be scrolled up in horizontal way in which the center image always looks bigger when come into picture & again scrolls the next image should come in center which is in bigger size.How could i do that? Thanks.

Comment: @YograjShinde I can use Galleryview.But it scrolls normally.i want the above mentioned scroll style such as center image should display little bigger in size while in focus.

Comment: check out this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html